# I need to use the format method to substitute an unknown number of parameters into a text file

Tags: python, file, text, format

The `pagesubs()` function reads a text file into a string,then uses Python's `format()` to substitute for arguments given in the subs parameter.

Here are examples:
My attempt was as follows:

```
def pagesubs(N,*subs):
    assert type(N)==str
    F= open(N,'r')
    return F.format(subs)
```

I get an error that `F is type(file)` but I thought the `open()` reads a text file into a string. Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT: Example

```
 pagesubs('index.html', 'December', 18, 2012)

  This will return the content of the file index.html, but 
  with "December" substituted for {0}, and 18 substituted
  for {1}, and 2012 substituted for {2}.
```

Comment: You'll need to add `.read()` or `.readlines()` to actually read the file.

Comment: `Open()` just returns a file object, you need to use some other functions on that object to read the text, read more [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects)

Comment: Will do... sorry I'm a programming noob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `read()` function on your file in order to get it's content into a string. Try the following code instead:

```
def pagesubs(N, *subs):
    assert type(N)==str
    with open(N,'r') as F:
        content = F.read()
    return content.format(subs)
```